# jQuery Ajax Issue - function to be executed when result returns only

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Below is the jquery ajax call I make to the controller

```
jQuery.post('index.php',{
                'option'    : 'com_test',
                'controller': 'product',
                'task'      : 'loadColors',
                'format'    : 'raw',            
                'design_id' : design_id,
                    'collar_id' : collar_id                        
        },function(result){            
        }).success(function(result) { 
                alert(result); 
            }).error(function() { 
                jQuery('div#color_wrapper h1').text('ERROR WHILE LOADING COLORS');
            }).complete(function(result) { 
                alert(result); 
            });
```

In my controller there is a function as below.

```
function loadColors()
    {
        die;
    }
```

My problem is even I have used `die` in the loadColors(), success and complete functions are being executed. What I want is a function which runs if we return something from loadColors() ? How can I get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would just check what the callback is and decide then what you would want to do.

```
.success(function(result) { 
    if (result == "") {
        alert("empty result!");
    } else {
        alert("non empty result! " + result);
    }
})
```

for example.

If you really want not to let the success function run via the PHP script you should check on other headers to give back before you die. I'm not fully sure if that works since I haven't used it before, but you can send headers that tell that there's an error on the page.

Comment: why does the success() execute when I have used die in the controller?

Comment: Because the request is finished perfectly, the result is just empty but the request did work like it should. Ajax doesn't really look to the result to depend whether it was a success or not. The success function would not be called if you would request a non-existing page.

Comment: what's the function to be executed if we only return something from controller?

Comment: Well, just like my example I would check in the result function if the result (which is the page output!) is empty or not. If it's not empty you can do your logic, if it is empty you can ignore it or give an error.

Comment: thanks a lot for the support. By the way I was wondering whether Jquery has a function to get that done.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think that jQuery natively has that. With this yuo can also be more flexible, you can for example let the PHP echo error codes, and then you can do in the JavaScript what you want, for example. if (result == "error_username") { alert('Username already exists!'); } or something like that. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

the `.success()` is unnecessary when doing `$.post` because the `function(results)` is only called when the post returns a success.

```
jQuery.post('index.php',{
               'option'    : 'com_test',
               'controller': 'product',
               'task'      : 'loadColors',
              'format'    : 'raw',            
               'design_id' : design_id,
                  'collar_id' : collar_id                        
       },function(result){            

          alert(result);
       });
```

is what you want to play around with.

Comment: why does the success() execute when I have used die in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

The functions success and complete are called because nothing went wrong in your call. You just return nothing. The error function is called if something with the call it self went wrong (i.e. Timeout or statuscode != 200).

You have to make your check in the success function.

```
...
success(function (result) {
    if (!result) {
        alert('Error');
        return;
    }

    // do the right stuff

})
```

Comment: why does the success() execute when I have used die in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger the `error` handler in the client's code, you should have your query return with an error code (`404 Page not found`, `500 Internal server error`, etc...).

Using php on the server side, you can use the `header` function :

```
function loadColors()
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    die;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support